# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewPresenter..ctor' not found

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I created Setup : MvxAndroidSetup

```
 public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext)
        : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new App();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => 
    new List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies)
    {
        typeof(Android.Support.Design.Widget.NavigationView).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.Design.Widget.FloatingActionButton).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager).Assembly,
        typeof(MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView).Assembly
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// This is very important to override. The default view presenter does not know how to show fragments!
    /// </summary>
    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var mvxFragmentsPresenter = new MvxFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(mvxFragmentsPresenter);
        return mvxFragmentsPresenter;
    }
}
```

I using mvvmscross Version 5.2.1
I have issue in line code var mvxFragmentsPresenter = new MvxFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);. when run project
 Visual studio 2017 in mac notify that:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewPresenter..ctor' not found.
  at VietOrder.Droid.Setup.CreateViewPresenter () [0x00001] in /Volumes/Data/Dev/VietOrder/Xamarin/VietOrder/VietOrder.Droid/Setup.cs:46
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetup.CreateViewDispatcher () [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Platform\MvxAndroidSetup.cs:124
  at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeViewDispatcher () [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:260
  at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary () [0x000f8] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:91
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.<InitializeFromSplashScreen>b__7_0 (System.Object ignored) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Platform\MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.cs:92
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) [0x00007] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00021] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00074] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your `MvxFragmentsPresenter` code.

Comment: Same problem.  I bet you it has something to do with changes to Android Presenter as described in in the blog for 5.2: https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-52-release/.  Digging in to see what the issue might be.  BTW, running VS2015 in Win 7/10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it but its been at the tail end of a long journey to upgrade to the latest MvvmCross version (5.3.1) from version 4.4.0.  I will identify the steps I needed to go through the upgrade.  It should be noted that prior to this I have updated all Xamarin and other packages to the latest and greatest and ensured the project compiles and runs.  In addition I updated Xamarin itself to 4.7.10.22 which brought support for Android 8.0 (I don't have an iOS front-end yet).  Here the steps I went through to update to MvvmCross 5.3.1:

- Upgrade all MvvmCross packages to 5.3.1
- Remove MvvmCross.Droid.Shared (4.4.0)
- Add MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Core.UI (5.3.1)
- Add MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Core.Utils (5.3.1)
- Add MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment (5.3.1)

Now to answer your questions, I changed my Setup class to subclass from **MvxAppCompatSetup**.  Call to the **MvxAppCompatSetup** changed to a simple creation of a new MvxAppCompatViewPresenter() (see below) plus removal of import of MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Presenter:

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
{            
   return new MvxAppCompatViewPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
}
```

In addition, since I was using some Fragments, I needed to change the Attributes on them from **MvxFragment** to **MvxFragmentPresentation**.  Last change was to change my main Activity from sub-classing **MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity** to sub-classing **MvxAppCompatActivity**.  All this did the trick for me and hopefully will help you.

P.S. I still have to change navigation to conform to the new NavigationService.

Comment: Thank @igor
I solved it by downgrade MvvmCross version from 5.3.1 to 5.1.1 because MvvmCross.Droid.Share current version 5.1.1

Comment: Yes, that will work but eventually you might be faced with the prospect of having to adopt the new Android presenter patter and the above steps will help.  Good luck.

Comment: @VermoricHuynh you should be able to forcefully remove MvvmCross.Droid.Shared (it's code is rolled into existing packages IIRC) and then update your other packages and it should work.