# MvvmCross 5.4 Custom Presenter: Method 'MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewPresenter..ctor' not found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

- I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802330/system-missingmethodexception-method-mvvmcross-droid-views-mvxandroidviewprese) and the solution isn't working.
- I've updated to the latest MvvmCross (well, latest everything actually) which is 5.4.2 at the time of this writing.

Here is my setup that registers my presenter:

```
public class Setup : MvxAppCompatSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext)
        : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => new List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies) 
    { 
        typeof(global::Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar).Assembly 
    };

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<INetworkManager>(() => new NetworkManagerAndroid(this.ApplicationContext));

        return new App();
    }

    protected override void InitializeLastChance()
    {
        base.InitializeLastChance();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IAnalyticsService>(() => GoogleAnalyticsService.GetInstance());
    }

    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var presenter = new MyAndroidPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(presenter);

        return presenter;
    }
}
```

Here is my actual presenter:

```
public class MyAndroidPresenter : MvxFragmentsPresenter
{
    public MyAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies) 
        : base(AndroidViewAssemblies) // EXCEPTION HERE
    {
    }

    protected override void ShowFragment(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (GoHomeHandled(request))
            return;

        if (ShowModalHandled(request))
            return;

        base.ShowFragment(request);
    }

    protected override void ShowActivity(MvxViewModelRequest request, MvxViewModelRequest fragmentRequest = null)
    {
        if (GoHomeHandled(request))
            return;

        if (ShowModalHandled(request))
            return;


        base.ShowActivity(request, fragmentRequest);
    }

    private bool ShowModalHandled(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request.PresentationValues == null)
            return false;

        var viewsContainer = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
        var viewType = viewsContainer.GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);
        var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, viewType);

        if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey(Utilities.Constants.Navigation.ShowModal))
        {
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);

            Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey(Utilities.Constants.Navigation.StayModal))
        {
            Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool GoHomeHandled(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request.PresentationValues == null)
            return false;

        if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey(Utilities.Constants.Navigation.ReturnHome))
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.TaskOnHome);

            Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is the one in the title. I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, refreshing NuGet packages all to no avail.

I'm a bit frustrated and at a loss. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure that you updated / removed  all the old android the dependencies of MvvmCross? I can't find `MvxFragmentsPresenter` anywhere in the Main repository of MvvmCross. https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-50?scroll=1300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presenter name should be `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter`. If yours is still `MvxFragmentsPresenter` it means that one or more packages are outdated. Look at the Playground sample to see a full implementation: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Playground

Comment: Must have been a package cache issue or something? I checked all of the packages in VS, as well as on disk in the packages folder, and they were all the latest (prior ones were 5.1.1). Ended up manually deleting them all from disk and running package restore and it's working now. Thanks!